# How are these Java byte offsets calculated?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

I have the following Java code:

```
public int sign(int a) {
  if(a<0) return -1;
  else if (a>0) return 1;
  else return 0;
}
```

which when compiled generated the following bytecode:

```
public int sign(int);
  Code:
     0: iload_1
     1: ifge          6
     4: iconst_m1
     5: ireturn
     6: iload_1
     7: ifle          12
    10: iconst_1
    11: ireturn
    12: iconst_0
    13: ireturn
```

I want to know how the byte offset count (the first column) is calculated, in particular, why is the byte count for the `ifge` and `ifle` instructions 3 bytes when all the other instructions are single byte instructions?

Comment: The second question seems pretty easy; the offsets take up space.

Comment: Note also that the article this code is likely from (http://cory.li/bytecode-hacking/) both explains this, and provides another link to understanding more JVM internals (http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JVMInternals.html). The JVM specs, as discussed in the answers, is the primary source, of course. While dense, ultimately you'll learn a lot more there than here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comment: The `ifge` and `ifle` instructions have an additional offset.

The [Java Virtual Machine Instruction Set specification for `ifge` and `ifle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.if_cond) contains the relevant hint here:

> *Format*
>
> ```
> if<cond>
> branchbyte1
> branchbyte2
> ```

This indicates that there are two additional bytes associated with this instruction, namely the "branch bytes". These bytes are composed to a single `short` value to determine the *offset* - namely, how far the instruction pointer should "jump" when the condition is satisfied.

---

> Edit:

The comments made me curious: The `offset` is defined to be a *signed* 16 bit value, limiting the jumps to the range of +/- 32k. This does not cover the whole range of a possible method, which [may contain up to 65535 bytes according to the `code_length` in the class file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.3).

So I created a test class, to see what happens. This class looks like this:

```
class FarJump
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        call(0, 1);
    }

    public static void call(int x, int y)
    {
        if (x < y)
        {
            y++;
            y++;

            ... (10921 times) ...

            y++;
            y++;
        }
        System.out.println(y);
    }

}
```

Each of the `y++` lines will be translated into a `iinc` instruction, consisting of 3 bytes. So the resulting byte code is

```
public static void call(int, int);
    Code:
       0: iload_0
       1: iload_1
       2: if_icmpge     32768
       5: iinc          1, 1
       8: iinc          1, 1

       ...(10921 times) ...

    32762: iinc          1, 1
    32765: iinc          1, 1
    32768: getstatic     #3             // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    32771: iload_1
    32772: invokevirtual #4             // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
    32775: return
```

One can see that it still uses an `if_icmpge` instruction, with an offset of 32768 (Edit: It is an *absolute* offset. The *relative* offset is 32766. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242438/how-can-the-offset-for-a-jvm-jump-instruction-be-32768))

By adding a single more `y++` in the original code, the compiled code suddenly changes to

```
public static void call(int, int);
    Code:
       0: iload_0
       1: iload_1
       2: if_icmplt     10
       5: goto_w        32781
      10: iinc          1, 1
      13: iinc          1, 1
      ....
    32770: iinc          1, 1
    32773: iinc          1, 1
    32776: goto_w        32781
    32781: getstatic     #3             // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    32784: iload_1
    32785: invokevirtual #4             // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
    32788: return
```

So it reverses the condition from `if_icmpge` to `if_icmplt`, and handles the far jump with a [`goto_w`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.goto_w) instruction, that contains *four* branch bytes and can thus cover (more than) a full method range.

Comment: Do you know why the offset (consisting of the 2 branch bytes composed into one 16 bit value) is restricted to a 16 bit size? What are the implications of this size restriction?

Comment: @jcm: Probably because a 16-bit offset is enough for by far most branches. The implication is of course that the occasional longer branch cannot be directly represented. If a longer branch is needed the compiler will probably generate a `goto_w` or something with the opposite conditional branch over it.

Comment: @jcm The implications are obvious; you can only jump 64K bytes. This works out well, since if you'd have followed up with the JVM specs, you'd find that a method maxes out at... 64K.

Comment: @DaveNewton: A signed 16-bit offset can only jump over 32k of instructions though. So if you wrap a crazy >32k bytecode method in an "if () { ... }", a plain conditional branch will not do.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Good guess about the opposite branch and the `goto_w` - see the edit.

Comment: The reason it is able to jump to 32768 with a 16 bit offset is because the disassembly is displaying the _absolute_ offsets, not the relative offsets. The actual value stored in the instruction is 32768-2 = 32766, which obviously does fit in a 16 bit int.

Comment: @Antimony Yes, I added this information, together with a link to the follow-up question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242438

Comment: It’s a funny thing that if the branches were defined to be unsigned *absolute* byte code positions, 16 Bit were enough for all purposes and `goto_w` entirely obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

The byte offsets can easily be calculated by summing up the size of each instruction before it. Instruction sizes are documented in the [JVM specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html).

The [`if<cond>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.if_cond) instructions take up more space than the others because in addition to the single byte opcode, they have two extra bytes that specify the offset to jump to if the condition it true.

If you want to experiment further, you could for instance try using larger constants (like, say, 20) in your code. You'll see that the instructions to load those will also use up extra bytes to store the constant value. Commonly used small numbers have one-byte encodings (such as `iconst_1`) for efficiency.