# How can the offset for a JVM jump instruction be 32768?

Tags: java, c, casting, jvm, specifications

While writing an [answer to a question about JVM byte code offsets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30240357/3182664), I noticed something in the behavior of javac and the resulting class files that I can not explain:

When compiling a class like this

```
class FarJump
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        call(0, 1);
    }

    public static void call(int x, int y)
    {
        if (x < y)
        {
            y++;
            y++;

            // ... (10921 times - too much code to post here!)

            y++;
            y++;
        }
        System.out.println(y);
    }

}
```

then the resulting byte code will contain the following [`if_icmpge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.if_icmp_cond) instruction:

```
public static void call(int, int);
    Code:
       0: iload_0
       1: iload_1
       2: if_icmpge     32768
       5: iinc          1, 1
       8: iinc          1, 1
       ...
```

According to the documentation of the jump instructions, the offset (which is 32768 in this case) is computed as follows:

> If the comparison succeeds, the unsigned *branchbyte1* and *branchbyte2* are used to construct a signed 16-bit offset, where the offset is calculated to be *(branchbyte1 << 8) | branchbyte2*.

So the offset is said to be a **signed** 16 bit value. However, the maximum value that a **signed** 16 bit value can hold is 32767, and not 32768.

The resulting class file still seems to be valid, and can be executed normally.

I had a look at the [bytecode checking in the OpenJDK](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/jdk/file/59deb2d00b29/src/share/native/common/check_code.c#l1160), and it seems (to me) that this is only valid due to the parentheses being misplaced:

```
int jump = (((signed char)(code[offset+1])) << 8) + code[offset+2];
```

It will cast the first byte to `signed char`. **Then** it will apply the shift, and add the second byte. I would have expected it to be

```
int jump = (((signed char)(code[offset+1]) << 8)) + code[offset+2];
```

or maybe even

```
int jump = (signed char)((code[offset+1]) << 8) + code[offset+2]);
```

but I'm not familiar with the type promotions and possible compiler-specific caveats of shifting signed and unsigned types, so I'm not sure whether there is a deeper meaning behind this cast...

So does a jump offset of 32768 comply to the specification? And does the jump computation code in the OpenJDK make any sense in this regard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument to `if_icmpge` is an offset, but javap shows the jump target as an absolute position.  That is, javap should show a `getstatic` at `32768:` and not `32770:` (i.e., 2 + 32768).

Comment: OK, that was simple. Indeed, when looking at the class file with a Hex Editor, one can see the offset to be 32766 (7FFE). I'll mark this as "accepted", but ... any thoughts about the cast in the `check_code.c` of the OpenJDK? That is: Does this cast make any sense? I think that integer promotion should take place regardless of this cast, and the possible *domain* of the resulting value does not seem to be affected by this cast...

Comment: I am not an expert on C type promotion rules (so I read http://icecube.wisc.edu/~dglo/c_class/promo_conv.html), but I believe all of those expressions are identical.  Starting with the inner most expression, I believe `8` is type int, which causes the left argument of `<<` to be converted to int.  The cast to a signed data type just needs to happen at some point (to allow backwards jumps), it doesn't really matter when.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple scala code to generate code to dig further. For all sorts of jump instructions, the offset is signed to support backward, and forward jump.

If the offset is less than equal to 0x7FFF, I see goto instruction, and if offset greater than 0x7FFF, I see goto_w instruction.

So, a method in Java is limited to 65535 bytes, because LineNumberTable, LocalVariableTable, exception_table... and is limited to 65535 bytes. JVM uses goto/goto_w instructions to jump signed 16/32 offset as needed.